# Passing state from child to parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I'm just starting with React and I came across a problem with passing states. Can I pass child state to a parent component to conditionally render other child components?

Comment: No, you can't. you need to lift the state up to the parent. [lift state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

Comment: you can't pass from child to parent directly. But a parent can send a method in, ex. `setCount={setCount}` from the prop to a child, so a child can invoke this method

Answer (score 2):

In React, you cannot pass state to a parent component. Instead, notify the parent component of changes using a callback function.

To do so, pass a function (defined in the parent) in the props of the child component, and call it when changes happen. The parent can then notify (other) child components through their props.

Answer (score 0):

Passing state from child to parent is remarkably easy - all you need to do is pass a function from the parent to the child which receives the state.

```
getState=(childState)=>{
//use state here
}

<>
  <customChild returnState={this.getState} />
<>
```

```
class customChild extends.... {

...
render{
<button onClick={this.props.returnState(this.state)}>Click Me!</button>
}

}
```

That being said, ideally you want the parent to control all the state values and pass just the needed values down to the child.  As the parent state changes the child will re-render that changed items.  This way your entire page has its state(s) all in a single location for debugging.